# explain behaviour of following StepRequest

Tags: java, debugging, jdi, jpda

I am running some program through StepRequest with following code.

```
EventRequestManager mgr = vm.eventRequestManager();
StepRequest st=mgr.createStepRequest(event.thread(),StepRequest.STEP_LINE,StepRequest.STEP_OVER);            
st.setSuspendPolicy(EventRequest.SUSPEND_ALL);
st.enable();
```

On `StepEvent` I am getting location of StepEvent using 
                `event.location().lineNumber()`.But the problem is, I am getting same line number for multiple StepEvents which should not be possible as I have given `STEP_LINE` as parameter for creation of `StepRequest`. But I can see those `StepEvents` with same line number differ on calling
                        `event.location().codeIndex()`
I want to know why I am getting such unusual results.

Comment: To answer your question, we would need to see the implementation of at least `mgr.createStepRequest(...)`. Please provide a [MCVE].

Comment: @Turing85 Its defined in java api https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jdk/api/jpda/jdi/com/sun/jdi/request/EventRequestManager.html#createStepRequest(com.sun.jdi.ThreadReference,%20int,%20int)